# How does Fabric Answers send data to the server, should events be submitted periodically or immediately?

Tags: twitter-fabric

I've used Fabric for quite a few applications, however I was curious about the performance when a single application submits potentially hundreds of events per minute.

For this example I'm going to be using a Pedometer application, in which I would want to keep track of the amount of steps users are taking in my application. Considering the average user walks 100 steps per minute, I wouldn't want the application to be sending several dozen updates to the server.

How would Fabric handle this, would it just tell the server "Hey, there were 273 step events in the last 5 minutes with this meta deta" or would it sent 273 step events.

Pedometer applications typically run in the background so how would we get data to Fabric without the user opening the application

Answer (score 1):

Great question! Todd from Fabric. These get batched and sent at time intervals and also certain events (like installs) trigger an upload of the queued events data. You can watch our traffic in Xcode debugger if you are curious about the specifics for your app.

Comment: So just to clarify, would it send 250 identical events over the network, or just send something like `{ event: {...} amount: 250 }` which would minimize network and battery impact.